# How to get ORB descriptors out of openCV as efficent as possible?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, orb

I want to store ORB descriptors calculated by openCV into a `std::bitset<256>`.

As there are several descriptors per frame/image I want to use `std::vector<std::bitset<256>>` per frame.

And as there are multiple frames in a video, the structure `std::vector<std::vector<std::bitset<256>>>` is used at end.

As openCV stores the desciptors into `cv::Mat`, I'm questioning myself how to get the descriptors as fast/efficent as possible out of it? So I digged around and found an [answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/102715/getting-orb-descriptor-values-bit-by-bit/) which does not use logic operators like `SHIFT` or `AND`. Is there any faster way?

Maybe there's a better struct based on `std` as `std::vector<std::vector<std::bitset<256>>>` to speed it up too?

Here's a short piece of code for easier understanding of the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  // opencv
  cv::Mat color, gray, descs;

  std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> kpts;

  cv::Ptr<cv::ORB> detector = cv::ORB::create();

  cv::VideoCapture video(argv[1]);

  // my desired datastruct
  using my_desc_t = std::bitset<256>; // one descriptor

  using my_frame_t = std::vector<my_desc_t>; // one frame

  using my_video_t = std::vector<my_frame_t>; // one video

  my_video_t my_video;

  my_video.resize(video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT));

  // processing
  for (size_t i=0,j=video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT); i!=j; ++i)
  {
    if (video.read(color))
    {
      // detect and compute
      cv::cvtColor(color,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
      detector->detectAndCompute(gray,cv::Mat(),kpts,descs);

      // fill
      // TODO

      // 8 (uchar) * 32 = 256 bits each orb descriptor.
      // how to use logical operators to copy it
      // as fast as possible into my_video?
    }
  }
}
```

I compile it with `clang++ -std=c++11 experiment.cpp -o experiment -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_features2d`

Comment: `Mat` has method `isContinuous()` if `true` then you can get a pointer to the raw data: `p = desc.ptr<uchar>(0)` but not sure this holds true for multiple descriptors stored in a `Mat`, i.e. padding/alignment, actually after looking at the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aff83775c7fc1479de5f4a8c4e67fe361) this should report correctly whether there are any gaps at the end of the row

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer

```
// bitset to Mat:

std::bitset<256> bs(11); // some demo value
Mat m(1,32,CV_8U, reinterpret_cast<uchar*>(&bs)); // 32 bytes

cerr << bs << endl;
cerr << m  << endl;

// Mat to bitset

std::bitset<256> bs2;
memcpy(&bs2, m.data, 32);

cerr << bs2 << endl;
```