# Is there a non-owning reference similar to std::bitset to provide bitwise operation and count for data in other container?

Tags: c++, c++17, bitwise-operators, simd, std-bitset

I am trying to implement a C++17 portable and efficient Hamming distance function for ORB features, hopefully automatically using SIMD when compiling for both x86 and ARM.

### Problem with `std::bitset`

`std::bitset<N>` provides a standard way for bitwise operation and count, and [it's also superior to `__builtin_popcount`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60165922/stdbitsetncount-vs-builtin-popcount). However, it's a container type that owns data, and is not easy to be converted from a 256-bit vector stored as `cv::Mat` that is computed by `cv::ORB::detectAndCompute`.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766667/how-to-get-orb-descriptors-out-of-opencv-as-efficent-as-possible) asks for converting `cv::Mat` to `std::bitset<256>`. I don't think `memcpy` in its answer is right, since I didn't find the memory layout for `std::bitset` in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset. Moreover, `std::bitset` constructor does not support to initialize more than `sizeof(unsigned long long)` bits.

### Problem with my implementation

To avoid copy, my current implementation use a span-like class:

```cpp
struct ORB_view {
  inline static constexpr int length = 256 / sizeof(uint32_t) / 8;
  const uint32_t* data;
};
```

However, this cannot use bitwise operation and popcount directly, and lead to explicit SIMD instructions in implementation, which I would like to avoid by using `std::bitset<N>::count()`.

### What I expect

As a result, a non-owning reference providing bitwise operation and count would be much helpful in such a case. The desired features are:

- no data copy,
- fixed length as `std::bitset`
- bitwise XOR operation and popcount
- no explicit SIMD code for ARM or x86

The standard library does not provide it as far as I know.

Comment: Just to point out the obvious, C++20 provides `std::popcount` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount) in `#include <bit>`.  If you can change the C++17 requirement to 20...  But that doesn't get you 256-bit XOR.

Comment: Thank @PeterCordes. Due to multi-platform support including Android, we cannot easily go to C++20 now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, if performance is important, you should stay away from `std::bitset` for most purposes. It throws exceptions on invalid inputs and those runtime checks are suboptimal for high-performance applications.

Secondly, if you were able to use C++20, you could use [`std::popcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount). Prior to C++20, you can use `__builtin_popcnt`. You have pointed out portability issues, but those can be overcome with conditional compilation:

```cpp
#if __cpp_lib_bitops >= 201907L // C++20 std::popcount
#include <bit>
using std::popcount;
#elif defined(__GNUC__) // GCC and clang/LLVM
inline int popcount(unsigned char x) noexcept {
    return __builtin_popcount(x);
}
inline int popcount(unsigned short x) noexcept {
    return __builtin_popcount(x);
}
inline int popcount(unsigned int x) noexcept {
    return __builtin_popcount(x);
}
inline int popcount(unsigned long x) noexcept {
    return __builtin_popcountl(x);
}
inline int popcount(unsigned long long x) noexcept {
    return __builtin_popcountll(x);
}
#elif defined(_MSC_VER) // MSVC
#include <intrin.h>
__forceinline int popcount(std::uint8_t x) noexcept {
    return static_cast<int>(__popcnt16(x));
}
__forceinline int popcount(std::uint16_t x) noexcept {
    return static_cast<int>(__popcnt16(x));
}
__forceinline int popcount(std::uint32_t x) noexcept {
    return static_cast<int>(__popcnt(x));
}
__forceinline int popcount(std::uint64_t x) noexcept {
    return static_cast<int>(__popcnt64(x));
}
#endif
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/qxfvrYh3T).*

With this wrapper ([taken from the `bitmanip` library](https://github.com/Eisenwave/bitmanip/blob/master/include/bitmanip/builtin.hpp#L400-L455)), you can call `popcount` safely for GCC, MSVC, and clang. The Android native compiler is based on LLVM, so it should also work.

It's very easy to create a a wrapper like:

```cpp
int popcount_256(const std::uint64_t nums[4]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        sum += popcount(nums[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Obviously, this could also be a member function of your `ORB_view`. There is no explicit SIMD-code, though clang auto-vectorizes this code.